# android how to find if a person is in call or no?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an android application. I want to add a timestemp meter to the calls. I don't know how to do this when making outgoing calls. I have to know somehow that the person which I am calling answered the call. How to do this?

Comment: get a response from the server, when click or press on answer button..  then starts the timing..

Comment: i am making an outgoing call on gsm . which server are you talking about?

Comment: It would be a big security compromise if the Telephony API provided ways to detect an in-progress call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I Know, it is not possible to have command in the ongoing call and also to automatically disconnect a call. Telephone API doesn't provide any methods to do any of changes while person is talking with someone.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to create a broadcast receiver as the following

```
public class CallListner extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
                //user making call
                }
     }
}
```

you need to add a permission on the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```